# Sed/RegEx - understanding a statement

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So I'm currently trying to reverse-engineer a batch of scripts passed down from our last SysAdmin.

There's a line in one of the shell scripts that I (for the life of me) am unable to understand. Here it is:-

`sed -n 'H;${x;s/^\n//;s/-jar\n/Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\n&/;p;}' "$File"`

GNU Bash 4.2.46(2) RHEL6 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command requires GNU `sed` and seems to insert the string `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false` followed by a newline before the first occurance of `-jar` at the end of a line.

Example:

```
something
something
something-jar
something
```

is transformed into

```
something
something
somethingDcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-jar
something
```

The `sed` command reads the whole file into memory by running `H` for each line of the file (appends the current line into the "hold space" with a newline character at the start).  When it reaches the last line (`$`), it swaps the hold space with the pattern space (`x`) and deletes the first newline (put there by running `H` for the first line of the file). It then substitutes `-jar\n` with `Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\n-jar\n` (the `&` is whatever was matched by the expression). It then prints the collected lines (`p`).

Another way of doing the same thing with `awk`:

```
awk 'skip==0 && sub("-jar$", "Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\n-jar") { skip=1 } { print }' "$File"
```

This tries to do the same substitution on each line, and when it succeeds it sets `skip=1` which will cause it to not try again. Every line is printed regardless of whether a substitution occurred or not.

This does *not* store the whole file in memory.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thanks a lot for the explanation on that!